# an RedisNodeNotFoundException was encountered when using redisson

Tags: redisson

#server version
redis server : 5.0.14
#
#redisson client version
3.13.6
#describ
private volatile Map<String, RedissonClient> redissonClientMap = null;

before our app link redis sentinel nodes,now our app will change link redis cluster nodes,implementation method is our app has a map to store two RedissonClient
one redisson client link redis sentinel nodes,another redisson client link redis cluster nodes, the map switcher is a key to routing a RedissonClient
but when we change key route to redis cluster nodes,After after a few minutes,app sometimes will print log

```
Node for slot: 1712 hasn't been discovered yet. Check cluster slots coverage using CLUSTER NODES command. Increase value of retryAttempts and/or retryInterval settings.org.redisson.client.RedisNodeNotFoundException: Node for slot: 1712 hasn't been discovered yet. Check cluster slots coverage using CLUSTER NODES command. Increase value of retryAttempts and/or retryInterval settings.
at org.redisson.connection.MasterSlaveConnectionManager.createNodeNotFoundFuture(MasterSlaveConnectionManager.java:579)
at org.redisson.connection.MasterSlaveConnectionManager.connectionReadOp(MasterSlaveConnectionManager.java:563)
at org.redisson.command.RedisExecutor.getConnection(RedisExecutor.java:644)
at org.redisson.command.RedisExecutor.execute(RedisExecutor.java:116)
at org.redisson.command.RedisExecutor$2.run(RedisExecutor.java:244)
at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelTimeout.expire(HashedWheelTimer.java:668)
at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelBucket.expireTimeouts(HashedWheelTimer.java:743)
at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.run(HashedWheelTimer.java:471)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

guided by logs,when we invoke CLUSTER NODES command, the redis cluster nodes status is health

tip:sometimes the app will print the following warning level logs
[2023-09-12 22:47:33.978][INFO][698][redisson-netty-5-14] traceLogId:[null] dstTraceId:[] TxId:[] SpanId:[] call [org.redisson.cluster.ClusterConnectionManager][checkSlotsMigration] 294 slots removed from

how to solve this RedisNodeNotFoundException,because it affects normal business logic,thanks help me